# Обновление атрибутов <input>: max, placeholder на основе пользовательского ввода

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Работаю над одним небольшим проектом в целях самообучения, столкнулся с проблемой, которую сам решить не могу. Прошу помощи.

Имеется форма со следующими полями:

```
<select name="location" onchange="??">
        <option value="">Выберите из списка</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<input name="name" onchange="update_form(this.value);">
<input name="volume" id="v2" type="number">
```

Необходимо, чтобы:

1. При выборе пользователем из списка опций `location` результат сохранился в переменную.
2. При заполнении поля с именем `name` запускалась функция php `balanceGr($name, $location)`. Функция обращается к БД mySQL и возвращает число.
3. Результат выполнения функции должен записаться в `max`и `placeholder`поля `volume`.

Т.е. идея в том, чтобы пользователь не мог ввести значение, большее чем есть в наличии на складе.
Перелопатил кучу форумов, понимаю что необходимо использовать AJAX с запросом,
нашел примеры, как можно обновить указанные поля с помощью `onchange`:

```
$('#v2').attr('placeholder', res).val('').focus().blur();
document.getElementById("#v2").max = "??";
```

Но как слепить все вместе?

Comment: `$('select[name=location]').on('change', function(){ ... ajax .... })` отправляете значение в пхп, он отдает json, из него ставите `$(#v2).attr('max', data.max).attr('min', data.min)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. На `onchange` `select` и `input.name` вешаем одну процедуру
2. Эта процедура, при срабатывании, проверяет заполнены ли оба контрола. И если да, то отправляет AJAX запрос на сервер
3. На сервере выполняем запрос к БД, достаем нужные значения и отправляем обратно
4. На клиенте при получении ответа на аякс модифицируем атрибуты `volume`
   5.Когда на сервер приходят данные `volume`, считаем, что атрибут `max` не был заполнен и валидируем значение сами

С учетом уточнения

> Пар name-volume на странице несколько (с разными id), location - общий для всех

схематично, это будет выглядеть как-то так

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var setAttr = function(AInput, ALocation) {
    // Реально, здесь аякс запрос
    $(AInput).next().attr({
      placeholder: AInput.value,
      max: ALocation * 10
    });
  };
  
  $('select').change(function() {
    var loc = this.value;
    if (loc !== '') {
      $('input[name="name"]').each(function() {
        if (this.value !== '')
          setAttr(this, loc);
      });
    }
  });
  
  $('input[name="name"]').change(function() {
    loc = $('select').val();
    if (this.value !== '' && loc !== '')
      setAttr(this, loc);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="location">
  <option value="">Выберите из списка</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div>
  <input name="name">
  <input name="volume" type="number">
</div>
<div>
  <input name="name">
  <input name="volume" type="number">
</div>
```

Comment: буду благодарен за пример. 
Пар name-volume на странице несколько (с разными id), location - общий для всех

Comment: @PavloHryhorash Добавил пример

Comment: @AntonShchyrow написал запрос, который возвращает корректную цифру в алерте: `success: function(data){alert(data); }` но не могу разобраться, как правильно передать ее Вашему скрипту

Comment: в догонку: в запросе `data: { "name":$("input[name='name']").val(), "location" : loc },` каждый раз у меня обращение идет  к первому имени, что не есть правильно((

Comment: @PavloHryhorash в setAttr уже передается конкретный инпут и конкретный location вот их и нужно использовать. Т.е. должно быть что-то типа `data: {name: AInput.value, location: ALocation}` В success так и писать `function(data) { $(AInput).next().attr({max: data});}`

Comment: @AntonShchyrow после того как `max` взял в кавычки - заработало. Спасибо большое! Единственный нюанс - поле `max` свою ограничительную функцию не выполняет. Заглянул в код - цифра туда подставлена, но, и в `max` и в `placeholder` перед числом как-будто перенос строки стоит, при этом `placeholder` отображается нормально. Но даже в таком виде уже можно пользоваться :)

Comment: @PavloHryhorash Попробуйте max устанавливать не через `attr()`, а через `prop()`. Хотя тот пример, что я привел отлично все устанавливает. Может проблема в выхлопе аякса?